# iOS -BTLE send data from central to peripheral

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

We are developing application using BTLE iOS.we want to notify peripheral that the has been received by the central with string it is more like a chat application. 
I have seen some question in stackOverflow [CoreBluetooth: How can the peripheral manager know that the central received an indication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130006/corebluetooth-how-can-the-peripheral-manager-know-that-the-central-received-an)

But i don't know hoe to proceed.. Any help is highly appreciate

Comment: Did you check this: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html ?

Comment: I seen that demo in that it only pheripheral can send data to central and not the central

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone corebluetooth central Manager send data to peripheral](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020782/iphone-corebluetooth-central-manager-send-data-to-peripheral)

Comment: Look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19022652/768935, it explains exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks.. Now I able to send the data from central to peripheral using [self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:payload forCharacteristic:[charactersitic.characteristics objectAtIndex:0] type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];.Now again I want to communicate from same peripheral to central by advertsing some data but i not able to do that.kindly help me out

Comment: @srividya, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602342/cant-write-value-from-central-to-peripheral-using-corebluetooth-on-ios